# I didn't get any confirmation from stripe after creating a charge. I know it's very common.But lot solution are didn't matching for my one

Tags: stripe-payments, strip, stripe.js

This is my checkout.php page. I cant see after this form submitting charge will happen on stripe.

```
<div class="row">
<div class='col-sm-offset-9 col-sm-3'>
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_Ccg6bLuZ261haQizFhV8Ma9k"
data-amount="<?php echo $amount?>"
data-name="Skarten.com"
data-description="Widget"
data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
data-shipping-address="true"
data-email="<?php echo $user->get_email()?>"      
data-locale="auto">
</script>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my process.php. But my problem is how to get any confirmation from stripe. If the charge is success or not.

```
session_start();
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
require_once('stripe-php/init.php');// add the php library for stripe

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_8UDgizhVo91Z8MJqk7G9n9BN");

// Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$amount=$_SESSION['amount'];

// Charge the user's card:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => $amount,
  "currency" => "usd",
 "description" => "Example charge",
 "metadata" => array("order_id" => 6735),    
 "source" => $token,
));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the charge is successful, the Charge object will be populated with something that has a Charge ID.  If it's not successful, that API Method `\Stripe\Charge::create()` will raise an exception (probably a Card Error exception).  You can learn more about those here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api#error_handling

Hope that helps get you started!

Comment: After the charge is their anyway to get the amount and other staff we already passed in checkout.php using $_POST[] or something. Sorry i'm new to stripe API.

Answer (score 0):

> The best way to get the 100% confirmation result is to use the [Stripe Webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#when-to-use-webhooks)

**Stripe will send a payload to your endpoint about any event what you registered**

Stripe will send you an [Event](https://stripe.com/docs/api#events) object which will contain specific event's response with details.

In your case you need to catch the [charge.succeeded](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#event_types-charge.succeeded) event which will hold the [charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#charge_object) where you can get detail info about it!